# How to check which files are being ignored because of .hgignore?

Tags: file, mercurial, hgignore

I'm quite often concerned that my hgignore file may be excluding important files. For example I just noticed that I was excluding all .exe files which excluded some little executable tools which should be kept with the source. It was a simple change to include them but makes me worried that the rules could have un-intended consequences.

Is there a way to view a list of all the files which are not being tracked due to the `.hgignore` file? Just so I can periodically review the list to check I'm happy with it.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The command `hg status -i` does exactly that.

Comment: beat me because I was too busy typing in the other characters to meet minimum character requirement :) _"body must be 30 characters you entered 28"_

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: I 've had that issue too... lesson: "if in doubt, be verbose" ;)

Comment: I always give answers using the --long-options anyway.  Better for teaching. :)

Answer (score 16):

@Jon beat me to the punch with the right answer, but its worth nothing that along with `status -i`, there is:

- `hg status -m` (only modified files)
- `hg status -a` (only files that were added)
- `hg status -r` (only files that were removed)
- `hg status -d` (only files that were deleted)
- `hg status -u` (all non-tracked files)
- `hg status -c` (files with no changes, ie. "clean")
- `hg status -A` (all files, ie, everything)

Answer (score 10):

If you want to do **manual inspection** on the file names, then use the `-i/--ignored` flag to status:

```
$ hg status -i
I ignored file.exe
```

If you want the **file names alone**, then use `-n/--no-status` to suppress the `I` status code printed in front of each filename:

```
$ hg status -n -i
ignored file.exe
```

If you need to **process the files with `xargs`**, then use the `-0/--print0` flag in addition:

```
$ hg status -n -0 | xargs -0 touch
```

That will take care of handling spaces correctly — with using `-0`, there is a risk that you'll end up treating `ignored file.exe` as two files: `ignored` and `file.exe` since shells normally split on spaces.

The above commands show you **untracked files matching `.hgignore`**. If you want to solve the related problem of finding **tracked files matching `.hgignore`**, then you need to use a [fileset query](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#filesets). That looks like this:

```
$ hg locate "set:hgignore()"
```

You can use filesets with all commands that operate on files, so you can for example do:

```
$ hg forget "set:hgignore()"
```

to schedule the files found for removal (with a copy left behind in your working copy).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is Possible. 
If You're using smth like TortoiseHg, You can select what files You wanna see.

Here's a sample

[image]